# get all header tags from php simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using simple html dom to do some scraping and would like to know if there is a way to get a collection of all H tags in one hit - that is H1 H2 H3 etc...

Something of the order of

```
$HTags = $html->find("h*");
```

I would then also need to know exactly which tag it was - `<H1> <H2>` etc..

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4):

you can do something like

```
foreach($html->find('h1,h2,h3') as $element){
```

Comment: thanks, I knew I could do that but the problem(?) is that it is to examine pages that I would not know if someone had used a tag like <H54> for css purposes. I had seen that there is support for wildcards on the release notes for the class but I haven't seen any example of it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try $xpath->query

Example:

```
/* The following example finds <h1> and <h2> tags in a html String and sets id to it. The html-code will be printed.*/
$html = "<h2>test2</h2><h1>test1</h1><h3>test3</h3>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$htags = $xpath->query('//h1 | //h2');
foreach($htags as $htag)
    $htag->setAttribute('id', 'test');

echo htmlentities($dom->saveHTML());
```